# Error filtering work items in Devops Track and Plan

Tags: ibm-cloud, devops

Sometimes, the filter by tags "#" returns a parsing error... it seems to happen on some tags most of the time and on a few tags almost never... please advise.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you initiate a tag search with #, the dropdown menu lists available tags. It also lists past searches initiated with #. If you initiate the search and then select a prior search, you end up with ##, which will produce a parsing error. In your example, I expect that the dropdown menu includes #api as a past search. When you initiate a new search and select that item, you get ##api.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using #tag? If I start the tag search using #, it throws the error before I add the specific tag.  I am unable to get the error as long as I use #tag.

Comment: I have learned that if you select one of the drop down queries that appears when you type # it sends the query with a ## which causes the error. It works if I don't select a drop down and type in the tag so that is what I am doing. Hopefully they will fix this bug... thanks for your help.